# Any anaconda command returned error "cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'"

Tags: python, anaconda

When I try to run any anaconda command (conda, upyter notebook, pip3...) in the terminal, it throws the following error:

```
>conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 36, in main_subshell
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/collections/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 109, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(main, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 389, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 20, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 52, in handle_exception
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
    from . import packages, utils
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 19, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pathlib
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/collections/__init__.py)
```

```
>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/jupyter", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import paths
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_core/paths.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
  File "/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
    from collections import Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/collections/__init__.py)
```

I have tried reinstalling anaconda, problem persists. Just running python is fine, and running Jupyter notebook in the anaconda navigator works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collections.Sequence` was deprecated in Python 3.7, but you're running a system-wide-installed Jupyter with a Python 3.12 interpreter using a Python 3.11 site-packages directory. That's pretty messed up... :)

I'd recommend starting from something of a clean slate:

- uninstall all traces of Anaconda, making sure `/Users/thejavanoob/anaconda3/` isn't a thing (you can rename it instead of deleting for starters) – if this succeeded, you shouldn't have a `conda` available on command line at all
- making sure there aren't any errant traces of Anaconda left in e.g. your system `PATH`
- uninstalling Python packages such as `jupyter` that you've installed system-wide (see `pip list`); if this worked, you shouldn't have `jupyter` at the command line at all

In general, unless you know you need Anaconda, I would maybe avoid the additional complexity it brings.